# How can I fix my script to send a string through a socket?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

To preface my question, I tried reviewing similar questions, and used some of those to get to my current code, but it still doesn't seem to be working for me.

I am currently using Hercules to send basic TCP messages to an active server (it is a simple program that connects to the IP/port and lets me send a message). I added a print statement to "message" and sent one using Hercules to verify my format is correct. So based on that seems like my problem is in sending the message itself.

My CSV file has a top row with an IP and port. After that each row has the data necessary for the message.

I get no error or any feedback at all. Hercules does give me an ACK message when I send it, but I am not sure how to see socket messages when using Python.

Basically my goal is to open a socket, then send a message. The format of the string is:

`<STX>1000000000^TEST^data1^data2^data3<ETX>`

Here is the code I need help with:

```
Tk().withdraw()
filename = askopenfilename()

with open(filename) as f:
    csvData = csv.reader(f)
    inputData = list(csvData)
f.close()

ip = inputData[0][0]
port = int(inputData[0][1])

s = socket.socket()
s.connect((ip,port))

inputData = inputData[1:]  #delete first row of CSV input

for i in range(len(inputData)):
    message = ('<STX>' + str(random.randint(1000000000,9999999999)) + '^TEST^'
               + inputData[i][0] + '^' + inputData[i][1] + '^' + inputData[i][2]
               + '<ETX>')
    s.sendall(message.encode('utf-8'))

s.close()
```

Comment: What happens when you run your code? Do you get an error? (If so, please include the message and traceback.) Or does it not send the correct message?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the ip and port are correct by the ridiculously simple debugging technique of printing the values? Show what is in the input file, or `inputData` by editing it into your question. Using the `with` statement means you don’t need the `f.close()`. Why not write a simple socket server which this code connects to and which prints what it receives?

Comment: Is <STX> literally those bytes or the control byte referred to by those letters (start transmission)?

Comment: @barny I did print those values and they appear correct. I will remove the f.close() for cleanliness.

Comment: Hang on, do you think you need to send e.g <stx> as text, i.e. five bytes? STX and ETX are (usually) ASCII control characters which are single bytes: STX is a byte 2,, ETC is a byte 3. See https://ascii.cl/control-characters.htm. So your code bulding the string to send should be appending `’\x02’` for <STX> and `‘\x03’` for <ETX>.

Comment: @barny That was it! it is only sending one line though, do I need to open and close the socket between every sendall?

Comment: Don’t know - depends what the receiving end expects. How do you know it is only sending one line?

Comment: I can run a sql query against the database that the server is connected to, and only 1 line is appearing, I am currently adjusting the code to open/close socket each time.

Comment: @barny I added a 1 second delay in each loop and that seemed to fix it. Thanks for the help.